# How to get an underlying element in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I have a table row and want to get a cell in the table like:

```
    <tr>
<td><input type="checkbox"id="delete" value="1"></td>
                    <td id="rowid">1</td>
                    <input 
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>test</td>
                    <td>email@gmail.com</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td>2018-12-31 09:28:29 </td>
    </tr>
```

I have jquery code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#clients').DataTable();

    $('#clients tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        $(this)
    } );

    $('#button').click( function () {
        alert( table.rows('.selected').data().length +' row(s) selected' );
    } );
} );
```

But how can i check the checkbox?

------UPDATE:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#clients').DataTable();

    $('#clients tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        var _element = $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]');
        var checkboxStatus = _element.prop('checked'); //true or false
        _element.prop('checked',!checkboxStatus); // If checkbox is 
        //checked, turn it to uncheck and if is unchecked, check it
} );
    } );

    $('#button').click( function () {
        alert( table.rows('.selected').data().length +' row(s) selected' );
    } );
} );
```

But now when I click the checkbox it doesn't get checked and the 'selected' class is not added to the .

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do? My answer below shows you how to check the delete checkbox (although I've tweaked the code to use a class selector instead of `id`). Let me know if that wasn't your desired functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append this code to **click** event of **tr** :

```
var _element = $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]');
var checkboxStatus = _element.prop('checked'); //true or false
_element.prop('checked',!checkboxStatus); // If checkbox is checked, turn it to uncheck and if is unchecked, check it
```

---

**UPDATE**:

If you want *ignore* click event on **tr** when your main target is chekcbox, handle with this code:

```
$('tr input[type=checkbox]').on('click',function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
})
```

Comment: Going to have issues if target of click is the input itself

Comment: When I select the checkbox itself it doesn't work how can I make this work?

Comment: @Sepehr Amirkiaee I want to be able to either click the checkbox or the whole tablerow.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the class `.delete` rather than an `id` as the checkbox will repeat for each row.

The code below recognises the click on the `tr`, checks if the `.selected` class is there and makes the checkbox follow that - i.e. checked if the row is selected.

Hope this helps

---

## Demo

```js
// Add click event to the table, for any row
$('#clients tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
  
  // Toggle the selected class
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');

  // Assign a checked value to the input within that row, the value should match the boolean check for the class active (i.e. false if the class is not present on the row) 
  $(this).find("input.delete").prop('checked', $(this).hasClass("selected"));


});


// Your button code
$('#button').click(function() {
  alert($("#clients tbody tr.selected").length + ' row(s) selected');
});
```

```css
tr.selected {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="clients">

  <tbody>
  
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="delete" value="1"></td>
      <td id="rowid">1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>email@gmail.com</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>2018-12-31 09:28:29 </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="delete" value="2"></td>
      <td id="rowid">2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>test3</td>
      <td>emai23l@gmail.com</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>2018-12-31 09:48:29 </td>
    </tr>
    
  </tbody>

</table>


<button id="button">How many rows are selected?</button>
```